# Excel: Imputing data when value appears in two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with four columns. Columns A and B reflect a list of unique values. Columns C and D reflect a list of non-unique values. All values in column C appear in column A. However, only some values in column A appear in column C.

[image]

**Question**

How can I impute the correct values in column D from column B as shown in the screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to achieve your results. Try one of these.

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$B$7,2)
=INDEX($B$2:$B$7,MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$7,0))
=XLOOKUP(C2,$A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7)
=FILTER($B$2:$B$7,$A$2:$A$7=C2)
```

For dynamic spill formula-

```
=BYROW(C2:C11,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7=x)))
=XLOOKUP(C2:C11,A2:A7,B2:B7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response. My real dataset has more than 500,000 rows. I was using XLOOKUP but was confused because I was obtaining "0" in many cells. It seems that XLOOKUP returns 0 rather than a blank cell when there is no value in column B. It took me a while to see a cell with the expected response

Comment: @C_H Yes, In Excel empty cell treated as `0` zero. If you don't wat to see `0` then could use a `IF()` like `=IF(XLOOKUP(C2:C11,A2:A7,B2:B7)=0,"",XLOOKUP(C2:C11,A2:A7,B2:B7))`